# Contour 3DPlot of four sets of data

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have four different functions that can generate four different datasets.

I want to be able to generate a single 3D contour of the result. I've tried many things and basically I am not getting anything that looks remotely what I want, a,b,c,d are constants in terms of the data which x and z are axes.

Here is my code which is pretty basic.

```
a = 2/Sqrt[3]*π; b = 3/Sqrt[3]*π; c = 2/Sqrt[2]*π; d = 3/Sqrt[2]*π; 
x1 = -(x*a); x2 = -(z*b); x3 = (x*c); x4 = -(z*d); 
data1 = Table[{x1, x2}, {x, -10, 0, 1}, {z, -10, 0, 1}]; 
data2 = Table[{x3, x4}, {x, 0, 10, 1}, {z, 0, 10, 1}];

Show[ListPlot3D[data1], ListPlot3D[data2, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

Comment: Your data is not in (x,y,z) form.

Comment: I know but should I rewrite it in x,y,z form?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, look up `ListPointPlot3D`

Comment: I tried that one.

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. Can you restate it? What are x1 and x2?

Comment: x1,x2,x3,x4 are all functions that depend on a,b,c,d and also x and z.

Comment: I see your point and x1,x2,x3,x4 are not in (x,y,z) form, as they are lines in 3D space. I've seen it is possible to do that.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to visualize? `ListVectorPlot[data1]`?